# Pandas showing only the unique instances of a value in a dataframe for a given id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the dataframe I'm working with.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['45', '45', '45', '45', '46', '46'],
                  'description' : ['credit score too low', 'credit score too low', 'credit score too low', 'high risk of fraud', 'address not verified', 'address not verified']})
print(df)
```

I'm trying to modify the the dataframe such that, for a given id, there are no duplicates of a description. The dataframe below is the desired output.

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['45', '45', '46'],
                  'description' : ['credit score too low', 'high risk of fraud', 'address not verified']})
print(newdf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the duplicates with [**`.drop_duplicates()`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). For example:

```
>>> df
   id           description
0  45  credit score too low
1  45  credit score too low
2  45  credit score too low
3  45    high risk of fraud
4  46  address not verified
5  46  address not verified
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
   id           description
0  45  credit score too low
3  45    high risk of fraud
4  46  address not verified
```

You thus can set `df` to the new dataframe, like:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```